# Observablecollection is not working with WCF data contract class

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, observablecollection

**Target:**
I need to bind the class to combobox and display a string value into it (The Name).

**The problem:**
The combobox(dropdown) is not showing none of the values if `Observablecollection` is created using `DataContract` class.

**Additional info:**
If I use a simple class instead of DataContract everything works fine!
I do not want to recreate the `Objective` and the other classes, repeative code is bad thing.

**The code:**

 
Services:

```
[DataContract]
public class Objective
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Objective constructor
    /// </summary>
    public Objective()
    {
    }

    [DataMember]
    public int ID
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Name
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Client- ViewModel:

```
public class SomeViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Objective> _objectiveList;

    public SomeViewModel()
    {
        this._objectiveList = new ObservableCollection<Objective>()
        {
            new Objective {
                Name="Task1"
            },
            new Objective {
                Name="Task2"
            },
            new Objective {
                Name="Task3"
            },
        };
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Objective> ObjectiveList
    {
        get
        {
            return this._objectiveList;
        }
        set
        {
            this._objectiveList = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Client- Window.Xaml

```
<ComboBox Grid.Row="0" x:Name="cbxTaskList" DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ObjectiveList, Mode=OneWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
    <ComboBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="SelectedObjective" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </ComboBox.Text>
    <ComboBox.SelectedItem>
        <Binding Path="SelectedObjective" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged"/>
    </ComboBox.SelectedItem>
</ComboBox>
```

**EDIT:**
I forgot to menthion that I'm implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` for my view model. Also **everything works fine if I'm using simple** class(Not the DataContract class).

Comment: looks fine to me, even if your ViewModel does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` you should see Task1,Task2,Task3 in your combobox, the only reason you don't must be the your `DataContext` is not set to an instance of `SomeViewModel`

Comment: I've also set the `DataContext` like so -> ` this.DataContext = SomeViewModel.Instance;` I have 2 identical dropdowns in the same window, one difference that I notice was the one class is implemented in services and other(that is working) in the client side. @decoherence

Comment: I found where was the problem... I had implemented some logic, that gets the tasks from server, before that claring that list. As there were no tasks to add from server to list, the dropdown was empty... Thanks for help, I will probably delete this question. :D @decoherence

Comment: glad that it worked, most of the time the problem is simpler than you think

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface for `SomeViewModel` class. Although `ObservableCollection` is a good choise, the XAML code is not modified when you do:

```
set
{
    this._objectiveList = value;
}
```

Instead do:

```
set
{
    this._objectiveList = value;
    PropertyChanged("ObjectiveList");
}
```

See  [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx) for `INotifyPropertyChanged` implementation details.

Comment: I'm so sorry, forgot to state that, I will edit my question. @Alex Sikilinda

Comment: Thanks for the help, that was my mistake, there were other logic implemented that was causing this issue.. @Alex Sikilinda